# Задавать значение константы в зависимости от конфигурации

Tags: php, константа

Название сайта хочу хранить в каком-нибудь файле, например conf.php, и значение определяю как

define("SITE_NAME", "Название сайта");

Хотелось бы иметь возможность переопределять значение этой переменной в настройках сайта.
Вопрос: есть ли какая-то готовая ф-я, или тут просто пофантазировать и написать свою?
Или, может быть, правильнее хранить название сайта в БД и вытягивать его постоянно?

Answer (score 2):

Создайте конфигурационный XML файл и храните там всю информацию, которая влияет на отображение сайта (название, язык и т.д.). Этот подход хорош тем, что парсить XML может почти любой язык на нативном уровне.

Answer (score 0):

:D - conf-.php - хороший подход.
Если все держаться будет именно на нем - попробуй перезаписывать его :)
А чо - вполне оригинальное решение :DDDD

Answer (score 0):

Константы переопредилить нельзя, да и смысла я особо не вижу, потом сами запутаетесь в своем коде.

Лучше как уже ты уже писал выше сделать класс/функцию которая будет брать нужню инфу из файла или бд и выводить как тебе нужно.